# AT+CMGS returning 'ERROR 2171'

Tags: serial-port, sms, avr, gsm, at-command

```
AT
OK

AT+CMEE=1
OK

AT+CSCS="GSM"
OK

AT+CMGF=1
OK

AT+CMGS="+44999999999"
> hello test message [CTRL Z]
```

At this point the connection hangs for 5-10 seconds.

```
+CMS ERROR: 2171
```

I have been searching all afternoon for a solution and am yet to find one. Everywhere specifies errors above 512 as 'manufacturer specific'.

Comment: Which is the manufacturer of the device you are using? Your question could also use some more explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @UncleO The manufacturer is `SIMCOM_Ltd` and the Model Number is `SIMCOM_SIM800L`. I am trying to send a SMS. Apologies for lack of clarity.

Comment: The [manual] (https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/sim800_series_at_command_manual_v1.01.pdf) for the Simcom 800 series only listed CMS errors up to 532. CMS ERROR codes relate to the message service or network. Perhaps the network you are using will have more information. (Maybe the device is just passing along the number from the network.)

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this error? I'm running into the same thing, I found a document that referenced some errors that included this error code but it wasn't very useful:
2170 - Enqueue faile
2171 - Not updated
2172 - State not allowed
This was from a company M10 AT Commands document but I can't find anything helpful in here.

Comment: Same problem, and modem reboot solve it. Looks as uncleO's comment is rgiht and this is just temporary network problem.

Answer (score 1):

2171 also apparently means "No 2G Network Available/SIM Does not support 2G".

I had this issue with SIM800L on a raspberry Pi using Gammu. Couldn't find anything about this error anywhere.

The SIM Card was Three (UK), which does not support 2G and that is why this error was occuring.

This fully stopped me recieving and sending SMS with this SIM.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).